# How do you make a textbox with required words js+HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Today I want to ask a question about forms(kinda). ok, so I want it where a user puts text in a textarea, but it will only go to the next page when certain strings are entered(kind of like codeacademy's editor)

```html
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>this is NOT a password screen!</TITLE>
    <SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
    <!--hide
    var password=prompt('Enter the text:','');
    var mypassword="word";
    if (password==myword)
    {
      window.location="pass.html";
    }
    else
    {
      window.location="nopass.htm";
    }
    var myword2="a password";
    if (password==myword2)
    {
      window.location="core2.html";
    }
    else
    {
      window.location="nopass.htm";
    }
    //-->
    </SCRIPT>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
  &nbsp;
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you post any code you've written, or ideas you've thought of?

Comment: perhaps using Substrings to ensure that certain input is placed in there. You could also run a command to remove all spaces and such and then compare the raw symbols with what the correct one would be, or if you need spaces just manually re add them in the correct spots.

Comment: whats a substring im a javascript noop pls help!!!

Comment: for the most basic questions (read: what's a substring)  use any search engine.  Stackoverflower users aren't here to google for you

Comment: yeah, but can you at least show me an example!!!!!1

Comment: @Jaket http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp  (first google result for javascript substring) has an example. I'm not sure what Ryan's intended usage was, you can use @+username as I did here to receive his attention

Comment: For all of you, what I mean is very simple. As most know, Substrings are parts of a String, as in a part of the Text. You merely have to grab the sections of text you wish to examine, and then compare. If you would rather just see if a certain word is in the Text, then use indexOf instead. 
var location = TEXT.indexOf("pass1"); If location > -1, then you have proved pass1 is in the variable TEXT, and location tells you exactly where it is (note, the count starts at 0 for the first character, -1 means before the first, which is nonexistent.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric does the better and more complicated answer and i agree you should not do this method for Passwords, but if you want one that is more on par with what you are trying to do, then use the [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) Function or the [Substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) Function depending on what you want to do.

```
var userInput = //however you choose to get user input
if (userInput.indexOf("pass1") > -1) {//user input has pass1 in it somewhere
    window.location="pass.html";
}
else if (userInput.indexOf("pass2") > -1) //user input has pass2 in it somewhere {
    window.location="pass2.html";
}
else {
    window.location="nopass.html";
}
```

indexOf returns -1 if the requested string is nonexisting in the original string, or a number starting at 0 if it is, where 0 is the first character. If you would rather just see if a specific area in userInput is a specific word, replace everything in the If statments with

```
(userInput.subString(0, 5) == expectedInput)
```

Note that 0 is the first character, and 5 is the sixth, but substring stops at the 2nd input and does not add it, so the sixth character would not be returned, just the first 5.

so if userInput is "thepass1", then the first part would simplify to "thePa", and if expectedInput is "pass1", then it would fail. BUT, if userInput was "pass1 is the Password", then it would pass, since it would simplify to "pass1".

In the indexOf examples, both would pass on the first check because pass1 is located somewhere in the string.

Comment: Thank u, Ryan that really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a contrived example for learning, as you should NEVER check a password on the client's machine in the wild.

Password checks should always be done server side, otherwise you are just putting the keys under the doormat.

That being said, here is an example in which you can *navigate to a different page* based on what the user types.  Your example led me to believe that each 'password' should send you to a different page.

https://jsfiddle.net/Ldar81s6/

```
//array of objects that store 'password' and destination
var passwordLinks = [{
  password: "pass1",
  page: "myPage1.html"
}, {
  password: "pass2",
  page: "myPage2.html"
}, {
  password: "pass3",
  page: "myPage3.html"
}, {
  password: "pass4",
  page: "myPage4.html"
}];

//define our check password function
function CheckPwd() {
var password = prompt('Enter the password:', '');
 //clicking cancel gives null 
 if (password == null) {
    alert("action cancelled");
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < passwordLinks.length; i++) {
    //object in the array at current position of our for loop
    passObj = passwordLinks[i];
    //if we matched, go to the page (I just did alert) 
    //also return because we don't need to check anymore, we have what we need
    //check against passObj's password
    if (passObj.password == password) {
      alert(passObj.page);
     return;
    }
  }
  //if we haven't exited the function yet, it means that we never matched the password
  alert("incorrect password");
}

//call our check password function
CheckPwd();
```

Let me know what makes sense/what doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Ok people, I'm sorry I didn't phrase this properly I wanted a thing that would handpick words like this:

food chicken ***box*** and if that one phrase was entered in any instance in the textbox, you would get through

Comment: Comments like this should be Edits to the original question, not answers.